# cbind or merge on multiple variables

Tags: r, merge, dplyr

I am looking for a way to merge/mutate these two data frames test and bind the X$x_i_plus variable to Y.

```
 XY <-  merge(X, Y, by.x = c("spd", "gender", "age"), by.y =c("spd", "gender", "age"))
```

I thought I would be able to merge by spd, gender and age but this did not work.

I also thought about using dpylr to mutate a new variable:

```
test <- test %>% group_by(qnhs, gender, age) %>% mutate(x_i_plus = X$x_i_plus) %>% ungroup()
```

This also didn't work.

```
 > X
       spd   gender   age   x_i_plus
   1    A      1   (0,18]        0
   2    B      1   (0,18]   401986
   3    A      2   (0,18]        0
   4    B      2   (0,18]   380446
   5    A      1  (18,45]   291854
   6    B      1  (18,45]   575662
   7    A      2  (18,45]   245701
   8    B      2  (18,45]   624040
   9    A      1  (45,65]   244692
   10   B      1  (45,65]   227710
   11   A      2  (45,65]   232654
   12   B      2  (45,65]   234826
   13   A      1 (65,101]   203882
   14   B      1 (65,101]   126477
   15   A      2 (65,101]   209999
   16   B      2 (65,101]   102736
> Y
      spd qnhs gender      age m_i_j  
  1    A    A      1   (0,18]     0
  2    B    A      1   (0,18]     0
  3    A    B      1   (0,18]   185
  4    B    B      1   (0,18]  3956
  5    A    A      2   (0,18]     0
  6    B    A      2   (0,18]     0
  7    A    B      2   (0,18]   172
  8    B    B      2   (0,18]  3656
  9    A    A      1  (18,45]  1542
  10   B    A      1  (18,45]  2863
  11   A    B      1  (18,45]   561
  12   B    B      1  (18,45]  3219
  13   A    A      2  (18,45]  1380
  14   B    A      2  (18,45]  2909
  15   A    B      2  (18,45]   637
  16   B    B      2  (18,45]  4117
  17   A    A      1  (45,65]  2060
  18   B    A      1  (45,65]  1921
  19   A    B      1  (45,65]   663
  20   B    B      1  (45,65]   987
  21   A    A      2  (45,65]  2033
  22   B    A      2  (45,65]  2191
  23   A    B      2  (45,65]   559
  24   B    B      2  (45,65]   899
  25   A    A      1 (65,101]  1604
  26   B    A      1 (65,101]  1500
  27   A    B      1 (65,101]    23
  28   B    B      1 (65,101]    27
  29   A    A      2 (65,101]  1712
  30   B    A      2 (65,101]  1112
  31   A    B      2 (65,101]    25
  32   B    B      2 (65,101]    27


> XY
      spd qnhs gender      age m_i_j   x_i_plus
  1    A    A      1   (0,18]     0       0
  2    B    A      1   (0,18]     0    401986
  3    A    B      1   (0,18]   185       0
  4    B    B      1   (0,18]  3956    401986
  5    A    A      2   (0,18]     0       0 
  6    B    A      2   (0,18]     0    380446
  7    A    B      2   (0,18]   172       0
  8    B    B      2   (0,18]  3656    380446
  9    A    A      1  (18,45]  1542    291854
  10   B    A      1  (18,45]  2863    575662
  11   A    B      1  (18,45]   561    291854
  12   B    B      1  (18,45]  3219    575662
  13   A    A      2  (18,45]  1380    245701
  14   B    A      2  (18,45]  2909    624040
  15   A    B      2  (18,45]   637    245701
  16   B    B      2  (18,45]  4117    624040
  17   A    A      1  (45,65]  2060    244692
  18   B    A      1  (45,65]  1921    227710
  19   A    B      1  (45,65]   663    244692
  20   B    B      1  (45,65]   987    227710
  21   A    A      2  (45,65]  2033    232654
  22   B    A      2  (45,65]  2191    234826
  23   A    B      2  (45,65]   559    232654
  24   B    B      2  (45,65]   899    234826
  25   A    A      1 (65,101]  1604    203882
  26   B    A      1 (65,101]  1500    126477
  27   A    B      1 (65,101]    23    203882
  28   B    B      1 (65,101]    27    126477
  29   A    A      2 (65,101]  1712    209999
  30   B    A      2 (65,101]  1112    102736
  31   A    B      2 (65,101]    25    209999
  32   B    B      2 (65,101]    27    102736
```

Any ideas on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: the coding for `gender` is not consistent between `X` and `Y`

Comment: I've just edited it, 1 and 2 are obviously factor levels for male and female

Comment: Now that you've coded it correctly (which, btw, was not _obvious_ to me), `merge(Y, X)` should work just fine.